# Just started learning and am stumped on my first assignment

Tags: python

I'm tasked with making a simple wage calculator. When I run it, it asks for the inputs just fine. But when it gets to the part where it performs the calculation, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/werpo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Wage Calculator.py", line 17, in <module>
    print (total_hours*hourly_wage)+(weekly_sales_revenue * commission)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Here is the actual code.

```
#Ask how many hours the employee worked this week and assign that value to a varaible
prompt = "How many hours did you work this week?"
total_hours = eval(input(prompt))

#Ask how much revenue the employees total sales for the week brought in

prompt = "How much revenue did your weekly  sales bring in?"
weekly_sales_revenue = eval(input(prompt))

#assign hourly wage and commision rate to their own variables

hourly_wage = (20)
commission = (.10)

#perform calculation for total pay as number of hours worked times hourly wage plus commision revenue times commission rate

print (total_hours*hourly_wage)+(weekly_sales_revenue * commission)
```

Comment: You should wrap the expression after `print` with parentheses -- this is not true for python 2, but you seem to be on python 3 where `print` requires parentheses around the whole expression.

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe how simple that was. You are a life saver!

Comment: Stop using `eval()` on your input. Use `int(input(...))` to convert to an integer (number without a fraction) or `float(input(...))` to convert to a floating point number.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The error is because of the `+(...)` after the call to `print`. They obviously intended for the whole expression to be the argument to `print`, and didn't put parentheses around it all.

Comment: This "hourly_wage = (20)" will create value as tuple/list. You should remove the paretheses

Comment: @NamGVU No it won't. You have to write `(20,)` to create a tuple.

Comment: You should print between parentheses: `print ((total_hours*hourly_wage)+(weekly_sales_revenue * commission))`

Answer (score 1):

Like trincot commented, you need to call `print` as a function with parenthesis. A few other notes...

1. You don't need parentheses around `20` and `.10`
2. You should not use `eval` to parse inputs, use `float` or `int` instead
3. Since * is above + in order of operations, you don't need the brackets in your final calculation either (but you need brackets around the whole thing to call `print` correctly)

What happens in your code is `print (total_hours*hourly_wage)` calls the `print` function and returns `None` which is normal for `print`, then Python tries to add the returned `None` to your second pair of brackets `(weekly_sales_revenue * commission)` which throws an error because adding `None` and `float` isn't allowed.

This is more clear when you reformat it like this
`print(total_hours*hourly_wage) + (weekly_sales_revenue * commission)`

Here's the code with my notes changed:

```
#Ask how many hours the employee worked this week and assign that value to a varaible
prompt = "How many hours did you work this week?"
total_hours = float(input(prompt))

#Ask how much revenue the employees total sales for the week brought in

prompt = "How much revenue did your weekly  sales bring in?"
weekly_sales_revenue = float(input(prompt))

#assign hourly wage and commision rate to their own variables

hourly_wage = 20
commission = .10

#perform calculation for total pay as number of hours worked times hourly wage plus commision revenue times commission rate
print(total_hours*hourly_wage + weekly_sales_revenue * commission)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why this resulted in the error they got.

Comment: Thank you everyone. You have been a big help. My instruction is an online course that isnt very thourough. You guys have already taught me mutiple useful things.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed, edited.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense. I understand why I got the calculation error at the end. But I'm not sure I understand why you are saying not to use eval? I literally started 4 hours ago and that was just what they were using in the example.

Comment: @AHalfSammich The `eval` function will just take any string of arbitrary Python code and then execute it and return the result. it does seem to work for parsing strings but that's not really what it is meant for and it's an indirect way of doing so. It's also not obvious what type it will convert to. To be honest until I saw your code I didn't even know `eval` would take a string and parse a number out of it, maybe someone else can explain better.

Comment: @AHalfSammich Also in general `eval` is 'dangerous' to use because it can execute arbitrary code. For example run your code and instead of typing a number type in `exit()` as the input, and it will immediately exit the script. Now imagine this is Python running on your server and taking input from users over the internet, they can shut your server down or read/write files or whatever they want

Comment: @Esostack oh ok, that makes alot of sense. Thank you for the clarification.